# Hyperlinks to tables that are in Appendix do not work well

Tags: tables, longtable, labels, appendices, ref

In my Thesis I have to add suplementary tables into Appendices. I have to referenced them in the text outside Appendices. There are some hyperlinks that works well, but others, like the example that I'm going to write here, don't work well. When I click to the first reference  `\ref{tab:BC}` it moves to the first table (that it isn't in the Appendices). However, when I click to the second one, `\ref{tab:Supl}`, that it would go to the Appendice table, It shows me the first table (which reference is `\ref{tab:BC}`).

I changed Appendices format to show me "Anexo" and "Anexo I". Also, I changed the name of the suplementary table (to difference it from the one that it's not in the Appendice) and its counter. Maybe it's the problem?

I tried a lot of things, but I don't know how to fix it.

I add all the packages and things in the preambule as I have in my entire document. Maybe there are packages that are not useful for this example, but I didn't want to change nothing just in case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}  
\parindent = 0cm  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhead{}  
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}  
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\usepackage{tocloft}  
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\setmainfont{Arial}  
\setsansfont{Arial}  
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}  
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}  
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}  
\usepackage[title]{appendix}  
\addto\captionsspanish{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}  
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}  
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}  
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize} 


\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. (Tabla \ref{tab:BC})

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. (Tabla suplementaria \ref{tab:Supl})

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft] 
    \footnotesize 
    \item[*] Footnote1
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{| m{1.7cm} | m{2.1cm}| m{1.4cm}| m{2cm}| m{4.4cm}| m{1.7cm}|}
\caption{\textit{\textbf{It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout}}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo (Foo)} & \textbf{Foo\tnote{*}} \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable:
\textit{It is a long established fact that a reader }(Cont\ldots)}\\
\hline
\textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo (Foo} & \textbf{Foo} \\ 
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{}\\
\endfoot
\noalign {\rule [-1.4ex]{6.7cm}{0.4pt}}
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
\label{tab:BC}%
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\roman{section}}
\clearpage
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage

\renewcommand\spanishtablename{Tabla Suplementaria}
\setcounter{table}{0}

\section{}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft] 
    \footnotesize 
    \item[*] Footnote1
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{| m{1.7cm} | m{2.1cm}| m{1.4cm}| m{2cm}| m{4.4cm}| m{1.7cm}|}
\caption{\textit{\textbf{It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout}}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo (Foo)} & \textbf{Foo\tnote{*}} \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable:
\textit{It is a long established fact that a reader }(Cont\ldots)}\\
\hline
\textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Foo (Foo} & \textbf{Foo} \\ 
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{}\\
\endfoot
\noalign {\rule [-1.4ex]{6.7cm}{0.4pt}}
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
\label{tab:Supl}%
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{10-343} & Foo & 2 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 1 & Foo & Fooooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 6 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
                        & Foo & 4 & Foo & Foooo (0.001) & F \\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Try placing `\label{tab:Supl}` immediately after `\caption{}`.

Comment: I think the problem is with the `\setcounter{table}{0}`

Comment: @C.F.G I tried what you said, also I tried to put inside the caption, but nothing worked.

Comment: @Guido I wrote `\setcounter{table}{0}` because I wanted that the tables in Appendices start with "1". (But with another name, "Tabla Suplementaria" and not "Tabla").

Comment: Add `\renewcommand\theHtable{Appendix.\thetable}` after your setcounter command.

Comment: did you already moved the \label{tab:Supl} in the \caption argument?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it worked!!!!! thanks you very much! Can you explain me how that command works? `\renewcommand\theHtable{Appendix.\thetable}` (I'm new in LaTeX and I'm learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to UlrikeFischer!

Solution:
`\renewcommand\theHtable{Appendix.\thetable}`